$\alpha \in O_K$ with all $K$-conjugates $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ , $|\sigma_i(\alpha)| = 1 \implies \alpha$ is a root of unity
I am working on this problem:
(i) Let $m, M \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the set
$$S_{m,M} := \left\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \mid \alpha \text{ is a root of a monic polynomial } f \in \mathbb{Z}[t] \text{ with } \deg(f) \leq m \text{ and } |\alpha'| \leq M \text{ for all roots } \alpha' \right\}$$
is finite.
(ii) Let $\alpha \in O_K$ such that all $K$-conjugates $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ satisfy $|\sigma_i(\alpha)| = 1$. Show that $\alpha$ is a root of unity.

This is my solution, I have already proven (i) ,but I am stuck at (ii)
(i) Let $f(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n \leq m$ with roots $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{C}$. By Vieta’s formulas, the coefficients $a_k$ of $f(t)$ are given by the elementary symmetric polynomials:
$$
a_{n-k} = (-1)^k \sigma_k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n),
$$
where $\sigma_k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ is the sum of all products of $k$-distinct roots. Since $|\alpha_i| \leq M$ for all $i$, we have:
$$
|\sigma_k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)| \leq \binom{n}{k} M^k.
$$
Thus, each coefficient $a_{n-k}$ satisfies $|a_{n-k}| \leq \max_{k} \binom{m}{k} M^k$, where $n \leq m$. Since $a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the bound depends only on $m$ and $M$, there are finitely many possible monic polynomials $f(t)$ with these conditions. Each such $f$ has at most $m$ roots, so $S_{m,M}$ is finite.
(ii) Since $\alpha \in O_K$, it is a root of a monic polynomial $f(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$. By assumption, all $K$-conjugates $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ satisfy $|\sigma_i(\alpha)| = 1$. Therefore, $\alpha \in S_{n,1}$, where $n = [K : \mathbb{Q}]$. By part (i), $S_{n,1}$ is finite.
How should I complete this argument?

Hint: consider the finite set ${\alpha^n\mid n \ge 0 }$. This is due to Kronecker, I believe.
